# Android Start Activity from a service without starting the other activities of the app

Tags: android, android-activity, start-activity, launchmode

I am starting an activity with Theme.Dialog on IncomingCall detected; however, when I start my dialog activity, it hides the Incoming Call Screen which is not the behavior I want. I want to start that dialog activity alone so that it appears on top of the incoming call screen and NOT the WHOLE application on top of the incoming call screen. I used the SingleTask in the Manifest and the NEW_TASK flag and used all sorts of Contexts.
as a hint, I want to do something like TrueCaller Android App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that the activity with Dialog theme has a different task affinity than the rest of your app. Otherwise, if your app is running, launching that activity (even with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`) will just bring the existing task forward and put your activity on top of that.

You should add the following to the manifest for this specific activity:

```
android:taskAffinity=""
android:noHistory="true"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

NOTE: Setting `noHistory` and `excludeFromRecents`ensures that this task does NOT show up in the "recent tasks list".

Answer (score 0):

use `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Comment: This won't help. The problem is the `taskAffinity`. Android is bringing the existing task to the front instead of creating a new one even though his activity has `launchMode="singleTask"`. Changing the launch mode will not solve the problem. See my answer.

Comment: thx for clearing .. +1.. I thought singleInstance would create an independant activity

Comment: It should. But alas, doesn't :-( Unless the `taskAffinity` is different. This is an issue that the documentation doesn't cover well enough, unfortunately.